# How to set up English(US) as the primary language on keyboard after tuning on the computer?

Tags: language-support

This is the input source in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my computer, **English(US)(en)** and **Thai(th)**. After turning on the computer, **th** is the primary language for the keyboard. Is there any way to get **en** come first ?
[image]